# Windows binwalk refuses to extract files

Tags: firmware-analysis, binwalk

I'm trying to reverse engineer the firmware for an AutoDrive AD-520 dashcam. The firmware is available for download [here](http://giinii.com/GiiNii/AD520_software_upgrade.html). I've installed binwalk on windows, I can get it to read the file just fine, here's a screenie of a regular `binwalk SD_CarDV.bin`

[image]

However, if I try pretty much anything else it doesn't work. I can't do -E, it just sits there for a minute then reads out the file contents like --signature, but doesn't do anything else, and trying to save the -E to a png I get an error saying "failed to import matplotlib module". When I try -e, I get a readout just like with --signature, but no actual files are created in the working directory. If I use `-e -C=./tmp` I get the normal readout, a tmp folder is created, but no files. I've tried `--dd=".*"`, as well as `--log=binwalk.log`, literally copied from the github manual, and I get this error (same error with -dd and --log)

[image]

I can't seem to get this thing to work. I'm wondering if it's me, windows, the firmware file itself...I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The syntax for binwalk arguments is "-arg value", not "-arg=value". If you want to extract image data you have to install matplotlib library for Python. Also, not sure if that matters but "./" is not the correct notation in Windows. use "C:\\tmp" instead (note the double \\).

Comment: Looking at the manual, I see that -D does use that syntax, but -dd requires the = sign. Either way, I've tried both. I installed matplotlib, I can now get an output from the -E command, I had to resize it so the labels wouldn't hide the graph: https://i.imgur.com/WRnDo0p.png Also here's a screenshot of the command window after running the -E --verbose commands https://i.imgur.com/AKe0tTS.png I still can't get anything to extract though, with -e or -dd.